# Animating elements height on hover

Tags: html, css, animation, hover, css-animations

I'm trying to animate the height of some elements **on hover**. I used the **max-height** to manipulate the animation as you can see here:

```css
.container {
  height: auto;
}

.hiddenContent {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

.container:hover>.hiddenContent {
  max-height: 250px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Hover me to expand</h2>
  <div class="hiddenContent">
    <h4>Hidden title</h4>
    <p>Hidden content lorem ipsum sid dolor amet</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Hover me to expand</h2>
  <div class="hiddenContent">
    <h4>Hidden title</h4>
    <p>Hidden content lorem ipsum sid dolor amet</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Hover me to expand</h2>
  <div class="hiddenContent">
    <h4>Hidden title</h4>
    <p>Hidden content lorem ipsum sid dolor amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem appears when I navigate from an element to an other: the 2 animation (the opening-one and the closing-one) are not simultaneous. The closing-one starts when the opening-one finishes. How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: reduce the value of max-height

Comment: still having the delay

Answer (score 0):

that's because you're animating max-height.
Here's a good explanation I found:

[CSS transition simultaneous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292875/css-transition-simultaneous)

just try to animate height

```
.container {
  height: auto;
}

.hiddenContent {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}

.container:hover .hiddenContent {
  height: 150px;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
```